# Find the longest continuous chunk of TRUE in a boolean vector

Tags: r, boolean

Given a boolean vector, how can I find the longest continuous chunk of `TRUE` and change the rest `TRUE` values to `FALSE`?

For example, given a boolean vector:

```
bool = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
```

How can I get a vector like:

```
c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
```

Comment: Do you mean the longest continuous chain of TRUE?

Comment: @MhairiMcNeill Yes

Comment: This sounds like `??"run length encoding"` (wink wink hint hint)

Comment: `r=rle(bool);r$values[r$lengths!=max(r$lengths)]=F;inverse.rle(r)`

Comment: What happens when you have more than one equal longest continuous chunks?

Comment: [Related challenge at PPCG.SE](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/80822/45941)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's an approach that will highlight all longest chunks of consecutive `TRUE`s in a boolean vector. That means, if there are, say, two `TRUE` chunks of the same (max) length, both will be reported as `TRUE` in the output.

We can use:

```
with(rle(bool), rep(lengths == max(lengths[values]) & values, lengths))
```

which means:

- `with(rle(bool), ...)`: compute the run lengths
- `lengths == max(lengths[values]) & values`: check if each run length is equal to the maximum run length where values is `TRUE` *and* also check if values itself is `TRUE`
- `rep(...., lengths)`: repeat each of the resulting logicals as often as it's own run length

OP's test case:

```
bool <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
with(rle(bool), rep(lengths == max(lengths[values]) & values, lengths))
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Second test case: same maxima for T and F:

```
x <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
with(rle(x), rep(lengths == max(lengths[values]) & values, lengths))
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Third test case: F longer chunk than T:

```
y <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
with(rle(y), rep(lengths == max(lengths[values]) & values, lengths))
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 16):

Using rle:

```
myRle <- rle(bool)$length
rep(myRle == max(myRle), myRle)
```

---

OP didn't provide answers to possible issues with this approach, but the complete answer is proposed by [docendodiscimus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37447844/680068) should cover all possible issues.

Comment: Wait a minute though. If we had a longer run of FALSEs than TRUEs this wouldn't work, right?

Comment: @MhairiMcNeill, `with(rle(bool), rep(lengths == max(lengths[values]) & values, lengths))` might be more robust though it would mark _all_ largest chunks of TRUEs (if there are multiple maxima).

Answer (score 1):

With inspiration from @zx8754

This should work even when the longest overall sequence is made of `FALSE`.

```
runs <- rle(bool)
lengths <- runs$lengths

is_max <- which(lengths == max(lengths[runs$values]) & runs$values)
rep(1:length(lengths) == is_max[1], lengths)
```

Comment: Ah yes. And I spotted a second problem when you have multiple maximum sequences. I think it should be right now for finding the first maximum sequence...