# Find the *first* longest sequence of TRUE in a boolean vector

Tags: r

I need to find the *first* longest sequence of TRUE in a boolean vector. Some examples:

```
bool <- c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
# should become
c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)

bool <- c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
# should become
c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)

bool <- c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)
# should become
c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
```

The answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37447114/find-the-longest-continuous-chunk-of-true-in-a-boolean-vector) handles all my cases correct, except the first one of the above examples.

---

How can I change

```
with(rle(bool), rep(lengths == max(lengths[values]) & values, lengths))
```

so that it also handles the first above example correct?

Comment: What should be returned when there is no `TRUE` e.g. for `bool <- FALSE` ?

Comment: @GKi: Never thought about that, because in my case there's always at least one element `TRUE`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option could be:

```
with(rle(bool), rep(seq_along(values) == which.max(lengths * values), lengths))
```

Results for the first vector:

```
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

For the second:

```
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

For the third:

```
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 5):

Not elegant but might work:

```
bool <- c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)

tt <- rle(bool)
t1 <- which.max(tt$lengths[tt$values])
tt$values[tt$values][-t1] <- FALSE
inverse.rle(tt)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

and as a function:

```
fun <- function(bool) {
  tt <- rle(bool)
  t1 <- which.max(tt$lengths[tt$values])
  tt$values[tt$values][-t1] <- FALSE
  inverse.rle(tt)
}
fun(c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

fun(c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE))
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

fun(c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE))
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

fun(FALSE)
#[1] FALSE

fun(logical(0))
#logical(0)
```